# Problem deleting animations

Tags: animation

So I have a character with multiple animations attached, however not all animations can be deleted while some others can. I use the same method on all of them yet those animations won't go away. As shown in the image, all animations with the prefix 0 gets deleted from the file, however the ones that don't show the number just stay there forever. The way I delete animations is by holding shift and clicking the x button formerly known as unlink. I've also tried space bar -> remove animation and they are still there.

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: Do the actions exist in the NLA? you may have clicked the push down or stash buttons in the header by mistake.

Comment: @sambler for me even if action is pushed to NLA it still unlinks animation in the Dopesheet if holding `Shift` while unlinking.

Comment: @MrZak when you add it to the nla it will be removed from the action editor, you can reselect it and unlink it in the action editor but the action in the nla gets the nla as a user preventing it from getting deleted when the file is saved but as it has a user it remains in the list of actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get rid of all the animations. Using the information given by sambler, i deleted everything inside the NLA editor, after that I went on to the action editor and shift + x all animations and now they are gone.